# PHP Composer pipe the output to the grep

Tags: shell, grep

How to pipe the output of the composer to the grep?

I've tried:

```
composer install --dry-run | grep -o 'test'
```

but I've got the same output as if there was no piping to the grep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `composer install` command outputs to standard error exclusively.
Only *standard out* is piped to grep so grep gets nothing and the *standard err* text is still displayed as usual.

To grep the output you can redirect *standard err* (`2`) to to *standard out* (`1`) :
`composer install --dry-run 2>&1 | grep -o 'test'`

Edit: See [shell redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) and
[file descriptors](https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-bash-shell-redirections#h7-file-descriptors) for more information.

Comment: Interesting, do you know why it outputs to standard error instead of standard output?

Comment: `compose install` does a thing and produces no output. The information text here is just diagnostics. With `compose show` the text is the useful output and outputs on stdout. 
In a script this makes sense when you want to take different actions based on outputs and at the same time log all errors and info from the commands in the script.
Say you use `sort` in the same script. You want to *use* the sorted output and add the complaint about locale (for example) to the *log*.